# Flutter how to swich BottomNavigationBar screens and titles

Tags: flutter, dart

I have BottomNavBar with 4 items, i want to change last item Login/Registration screen to profile screen when user is authorized, i check auth with sharedPreferencies plugin,
I can't create a condition in my code that will change screens and titles
my code:

```
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    await getToken();
    print(val);
  }
  late final String? val;
  getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Constants.USER_TOKEN = pref.getString('login') ?? "";
    setState(() {
      val = Constants.USER_TOKEN;
    });
  }
  late int currentIndex;
  final List<String> screenTitles = ['Главная', 'Каталог', 'Корзина', 'Войти'];
  final screens = [
    HomePage(),
    CatalogPage(),
    ShoppingBag(),
    Login(),
  ];

//it should look like this
  // if(val != null && val != '') {
  //   return ProfilePage();
  // } else { 
  //   return Login();
  // }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `getToken` to this:

```
getToken() async {
      SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      Constants.USER_TOKEN = pref.getString('login') ?? "";
      val = Constants.USER_TOKEN;
      screens = [
        HomePage(),
        CatalogPage(),
        ShoppingBag(),
        val != null && val != '' ? ProfilePage(): Login(),
      ];
      setState(() {});
    }
```